# iOS8 and AFNetworking/NSHTTPSession with HTTP 302

Tags: amazon-s3, ios8

Looks like NSUrlSession/Task behavior has changed with iOS8. My app uses AFNetworking layer for managing background download tasks.
It sends a GET request to the backend (java/dropwizard) which responds with HTTP 302 redirect with AWS S3 location.
By the time completion handler is invoked I get an error domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" "The requested URL was not found on this server." 
I confirmed that resource does exist at specified S3 URL location.

After spending a long time I realized that problem is likely related to the fact that HTTP header "Authorization" that is supposed to be included in the initial request to my backend is now also included in the redirected request to AWS S3 resource. I don't think that was a case for iOS7.*
Apparently S3 request fails when "Authorization" header is included (confirmed with curl).

I tried to define a handler for setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock so I can issue a new request without offending header. Unfortunately my handler is not being invoked.

I would apreciate any suggestions/ideas people may have on this.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. In sessions with a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, the

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
    newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler;
```

delegate method is never called. From Apples documentation:

> This method is called only for tasks in default and ephemeral sessions. Tasks in background sessions automatically follow redirects.

Fine. The problem then is that `NSURLSession` is forwarding `Authorization` headers across hostnames in the redirect, and you have no way of changing that. Which to me sounds like a security issue, in addition to stopping redirect to S3 (and Azure). This problem seems to have been introduced in iOS8 because I see people with the opposite problem, where the `Authorization` header is lost in the redirect, from dates before iOS 8 launched.

One (ugly) way of solving it is to change the header to something custom, like `Authorization_` if you control the backend where the redirect is happening. S3 will ignore that header. But then you're still leaking credentials…